# Surface area with cavalier's principle

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The formula for the lateral surface area of an oblique cylinder as shown in the picture (linked because I can't post images) is
$$A=2\pi ra$$
or 
$$A =\frac{2\pi rh}{\sin(v)}$$

[oblique cylinder](http://www.mathinary.com/images/cylinder_oblique.png)

This makes intuitive sense by Cavalieri's principle, but how would one prove it explicitly by integration? Is there a parametrisation for the cylinder which we could integrate to get the surface area?

Comment: And here I thought cavalier attitude has no place in math

Comment: Cavalieri's principle doesn't work for surface areas in $\Bbb R^3$, does it?

Comment: I think Cavalieri's principle is used to calculate volumes of solids and not surface areas.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Set up a parametrical representation in the form
$$(\phi,s)\mapsto {\bf r}(\phi,s):=(r\cos\phi+ s\cos v,r\sin\phi, s\sin v)\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq2\pi, \ 0\leq s\leq a)\ ,$$
and compute the area according to the standard formula. You will obtain
$${\rm area}(S)=ar\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi}\>d\phi\ .$$
From this we can draw two conclusions, namely (i) that the area cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, and (ii) that the intuitive approach using Cavalieri's principle does not lead to the correct result. (I was surprised, too.)

The formula ${\rm area}(S)=2\pi ar$ is only correct, if $\theta={\pi\over2}$. In fact one easily verifies "geometrically" that in the case $\theta=0$ one has ${\rm area}(S)=4 ar$, which is also the value produced by the above formula.

Comment: I end up with the following integral which I can't evaluate - have I gone wrong?  $ar\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(v)}d\phi$

Comment: Does this mean the formula $A=2\pi ra$ is somehow incorrect? Or is there a better way prove it using calculus?

Comment: Cavalieri's principle is used for volumes of solids and not surface areas. The right approach to surface areas is through integrals as you have shown. +1